# Symfony 2: Setting a cookie for the current session upon login

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to set a session cookie, upon successful login? An event listener? If so, which event? And how i can access the response object to attach the cookie to it?

Comment: Is it necessary to be a cookie, or is it enough to store it in the session?

Comment: It has to be a cookie!

Comment: ping! you got a answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an EventListener which listens to the [kernel.response Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-response-event) and modify the response.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class AddMyCookie
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        if (/** whatever **/) {
            $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value'));
        }
    }
}
```

in your services.yml:

```
parameters:
    acme_demo.add_my_cookie.class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AddMyCookie

services:
    acme_demo.add_my_cookie.kernel_response_listener:
        class: %acme_demo.add_my_cookie.class%
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Whatever you need to decide to set the cookie (security_context, usermanager, session, etc.) can be injected trough the DI Container.

Comment: What is `/** whatever **/`? Can you please add an example?

Comment: Whatever decision you are making to add the cookie, should go into the if.

Comment: Like checking credentials? I think you should add a small example.

Comment: @PatrikKarisch - I'm using this & it's all working, until I got to your DI Container part - I'm confused about that, how to get the info I need to set the cookie. Do you have an example?

Comment: Which info. It depends all on which info you are dependent to make the decision. Also note the DI config was written in times of Symfony 2.3. Should still work in 3.x and 4.x, but can be simplified.